# php - reduzir tamanho de imagem

Tags: php

Criei este codigo de upload de imagens.
Mas sabendo que certa gente pode por imagens de 2000x1000, 5mb
Gostaria de reduzir isso para algo mt menor.
E inserir no meu codigo, como poderei fazer?

Comment: Alguem possivelmente poderia ajudar?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/features.file-upload.php

Answer (score -1):

Dá uma olhada nesse video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GBMXmDBXK7M Ele fala sobre como redimensionar imagens, elas ficam menores ao serem redimensionadas, você pode deixá-las do tamanho que desejar e você também pode limitar o tamanho da imagem, assim por exemplo:

```
$tamanhoPermitido = 1024 * 1024;

$tamanho = $_FILES['file']['size'];

if ($tamanho > $tamanhoPermitido) {?>
   O tamanho do arquivo enviado é maior que o limite!

                <?php }?>
```

OBS: cara, o amigo acima está tentando te ajudar e é assim que você responde?

> Citação

```
@hugocsl .. continuo na mesma, pois pretendo é ajudinha a desenvolver e a explicar um codigo de reducao de tamanho. Voces dão-me respostas tortas e... sem sentido para a minha questão.
```

Assim que o pessoal não vai te ajudar mesmo.